# Delete Excel Column If 1000> Cells Are Empty

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

I just populated a table via an algorithm with data from an Autodesk file.  A good many of the fields are empty, and, in fact, a number of columns are empty but for a few rows.  There are roughly 1300 columns, and I'm trying to trim that down.

Can anyone help me out with the VBA to remove a column if there are more than 1000 rows where the column is empty?  I don't really know any VBA, so I don't know where to begin...

I'm trying something like this:

```html
Sub ClearColumns()
'
' ClearColumns Macro
' Check to see if more than 1000 rows of a column are empty.  If so, delete the column.

Dim iColumn As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iColumnMax As Long
Dim iRowMax As Long
Dim iEmptyCount
iColumnMax = 13000
iRowMax = 20000

For iColumn = 1 To iColumnMax
    For iRow = 1 To iRowMax
        If (Cells(iRow, iColumn) = "") Then iEmptyCount.Add (1)
        End If
    If (iEmptyCount > 999) Then Columns(iColumn).Delete
    Step 1
    End If
Step 1     
Application.Goto Reference:="ClearColumns"
End Sub
```

But again, I don't know what I'm doing.  Any help/feedback is appreciated

Comment: But there are millions of cells in each column...........most of the bottom cells will be empty!

Comment: OK.  Then with a range of rows...  Like RowMax = 20000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

Dim ColNumber as Long

For ColNumber = 1300 to 1 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Cells(1, ColNumber).Resize(20000,1)) > 1000 Then
        Cells(1,ColNumber).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code that removes a completely empty column.
The last column is allocated on the first line, that is, the stub cell in the first line must be filled with any sign.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
Dim i As Long, lc As Long, lr As Long

lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lc

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
If IsEmpty(Cells(lr, i)) = True Then
Cells(lr, i).EntireColumn.Delete
i = i - 1
lc = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If lc = i Then Exit For
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I will never have a completely empty column - just a MOSTLY empty column.  That's why I need to check if more than 1000 rows are empty for each column

Comment: it should be empty starting from the first line, or 1000 rows can be in the middle of the column?

Answer (score 1):

This is credited to @Jeeped from a 2015 solution. It will remove all empty cells in your used range.

```
 With Worksheets("name of your worksheet")
     .UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
 End With
```